# survey on zero knowledge proof

Tags: zero-knowledge-proofs

Is there a recent and comprehensive survey on zero knowledge proofs? I'm trying to find one which provide more details than the two chapters (19/20) in Boneh and Shoup's book (a grad course in applied cryptography)

Answer (score 3):

Here's a recent doctoral thesis with a decent literature review.
https://discovery.ucl.ac.uk/id/eprint/10073525/

Comment: Thanks for the information!